# React Native Webview NSURLErrorDomain 1022

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to display custom urls (they are not the ones in the exceptions domains, they are others and I don't always know their domain) in a web view component but can't seem to fix Apple's error 1022 : `The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection`

My `Info.plist` file has the following :

```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>needl-app.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your domain keys with:

`<key>www.akamaihd.net</key>`

and

`<key>www.faceboook.com</key>`

That seemed to solve the issue for me. Also, for facebook, you can remove it as long as in your webview you route to https://www.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same error. It appears that you can't load an insecure webpage unless you explicitly add them to `NSExceptionDomains` in **iOS 9**.

You can consider [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/index.html) for your use case.

> Use the SFSafariViewController class if your app lets users view
>   websites from anywhere on the Internet.

SFSafariViewController is not shipped with react-native currently. But you can create a [custom native component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#content) yourself.